# Can '_id' be mapped with Java UUID?

Tags: java, mongodb, scala, playframework, reactivemongo

Initially I wanted to map MongoDB's `_id` in my models. For example:

```
case class User(_id: Option[BSONObjectID], ...)
```

However, this caused a lot of problems because I had to set the `_id` after I inserted a user document. Therefore, I replaced this attribute by using Java's `UUID` class. Which means that I will have only `id` in my model and `_id` as well as `id` in the database. I started to use this now for all my models, because I think it's a bad practice to store database-related info in my models (what if I switch to a SQL database?). Can I use `UUID`s as a valid replacement for `_id` for all my documents?

Comment: Nothing prevent you from replacing the default `_id` by a string one generated by `UUID`.

Comment: Okay, but can I rely safely on using a generated `UUID` for all documents instead of `_id`, or how do people deal with this issue? I think it's not a good idea to make my models dependent on the database layer I am using, is it?

Comment: That's more a design question, depending on your project, rather than a technical question

Answer (score -1):

Just discussing from design point of view: even if you move to (MS/My)SQL some day you would have `primary key autoincrement` like key for your table, which would be same as `_id` of mongodb collection. So is `_id` really a database-related info ?

Comment: Better to be added as a comment

Comment: @cchantep Thats what i wanted but site doesn't allow me to add comment yet (not enough reputation points yet). In case you have downvoted, for the same reason, pls remove it.